# get rows from dataframe matching element of a list

Tags: r, dataframe, match

Here are one dataframe/tibble and one character element(this element is one column of a tibble)

```
df1 <- structure(list(Twitter_name = c("CHESHIREKlD", "JellyComons", 
"kirmiziburunlu", "erkekdeyimleri", "herosFrance", "IkishanShah"
), Declared_followers = c(60500L, 43100L, 31617L, 27852L, 26312L, 
16021L), Real_followers = c(60241, 43054, 31073, 27853, 25736, 
15856), Twitter_Id = c("783866366", "1424086592", "2367932244", 
"3352977681", "2580703352", "521094407")), .Names = c("Twitter_name", 
"Declared_followers", "Real_followers", "Twitter_Id"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

myId <- c("867211097882804224", "868806957133688832",   "549124465","822580282452754432",  
"109344546", "482666188", "61716107", "3642392237", "595318933", 
"833365943044628480", "1045015087", "859830740669800448", "860562940059045888", 
"2854457294", "871784135983067136", "866922354554814464", "4839343547", 
"849451474572759040", "872084673526214656", "794841530053853184")
```

**N:B**: `df1` has been shortened and has indeed 128 observations.
I am looking to test all row elements of `df1$Twitter_Id` and see if they are in `myId`. I can run this:

```
 > match(myId[1], df1$Twitter_Id)
```

but:

1. it stops at the first occurrence
2. I need to apply the `match()` function to all elements of `myId`.

I can't find a clean and simple way to do this, using `lapply()` or other functions from `dplyr`, `tydiverse` packages.

Thank you for help.

**EDIT** I need to be more explicit with the whole real case.

```
myTw <- structure(list(id_str = c("893445199661330433", "893116842558050304", 
"892739336466305024", "892401780105019393", "892401594272296963", 
"892365572486430720", "891964139756818432")), .Names = "id_str", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

these are tweets ID.What I am looking for is to obtain which twitter users have retweeted these ones. To do this, I use the `retweeters()` function from package `twitteR`.

```
library(twitteR)
MyRtw <- retweeters(myTw[1])

MyRtw <- c("889135428028084224", "867211097882804224", "868806957133688832", 
"549124465", "822580282452754432", "109344546", "482666188", 
"61716107", "3642392237", "595318933", "833365943044628480", 
"1045015087", "859830740669800448", "860562940059045888", "2854457294", 
"871784135983067136", "866922354554814464", "4839343547", "849451474572759040", 
"872084673526214656")
```

This is a list of Twitter user Id. 
Now finally I want to see which users from `df1$Twitte_Id` have retweeted `MyTw[1]`.

Comment: Why not `df1$Twitter_Id %in% myID`?

Comment: @Sotos I may have wrongly expressed the problem, but your solution is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Jaap no, your solution will only give me the result for first element in myId. I need to test for all elements.

Comment: @Sotos this is not what I expect. Let me edit my question as it seems I didn't tell right.

Comment: @gabx: The solution of Jaap is definitely not give you only the first element. It returns a boolean-vector where every bool represents the occurence in your id-vector (myId) -> see my solution

Comment: @gabx Did you test it? Using `%in%` will test for all elements in `myId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '%in%' operator.

**Edit: Probably this is what you want. Here I used the data posted in your original post (before editing).**

```
matchVector = NULL
for (id in df1$Twitter_Id) {
  matchCounter <- sum(myId %in% id)  
  matchVector <- c(matchVector, matchCounter)
}

df1$numberOfMatches <- matchVector
```

Comment: thats a first good step, thank you. But now I need to apply this to all elements of what I called MyRtw in my edit. I was thinking of replacing FALSE by 0 and TRUE by 1 and thus get how my retweets each user of df1 did.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see the connection between all the data points. You have twitter-users in df1. You have tweet IDs in myTw, you have a vector with user-IDs in MyRtw and than you also have a vector with user-IDs in myId. Is myId the same as MyRtw. Am I right that I can ignore myId after your edit?

Comment: If my new solution is not what you are searching for, please add the desired output to your question. Please also add some positive results since at the moment there are no matches in your example data and we don't know exactly whether there can be multiple matches or how your desired output should be in general.